# How do i reach the end of an array using a register?

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips, mips32

i am trying to invert the elements of an array in MIPS assembly. For example if the array is 1 2 3 it should be 3 2 1 after this function. I think my solution works but my problem is how to reach the last element of the array because the size of the array is saved in register $t1 but i don't think i can do this `lb $t0, $t1($a0)`. Is there another way to go about this?

```
INVERT:
#$a0 is the array
#$a1 is its size
move $t1, $a1
sra $a1, $a1, 1 #half the size of the array

beq $a1, $zero, end
add $a1, $a1, -1

next:
lb $t0, 0($a0) #t0 = array[i]
add $a0, $a0, 4
move $t2, $t0 #aux = array[i]
lb $t0, $t1($a0) # t0 = array[end]
sb $t0, 0($a0) #array[i] = array[end]
sb $t2, $t1($a0) #array[end] = aux <- previous array[i]

j next
nop

end:
```

edit:nevermind, its getting way too confusing, i should just start over in a different way

Comment: You can do the addition separately into a temporary register which may of course be your destination. For example: `add $t0, $t1, $a0; lb $t0, ($t0)`

Comment: you need to have an exit condition test inside the loop, or else it will never end, except by crashing.